# Routing from slug url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I'm currently writing a PHP application, and I have always used frameworks and always worked in larger projects, but for this particular project I am doing neither. I've hit an issue where if I go to:

```
http://localhost/project
```

It runs the index.php file fine, but if I wanted to go to

```
http://localhost/project/test
```

I'd still want it to run the index.php file, and work out what to do with the 'test' part from there. Instead I'm getting a 404. How do I go about this?

I'm using Apache as my server, is it something I need to change in the .htaccess file? I'm pretty new to editing that file and have found most tutorials haven't said how to do this, but it seems like a pretty integral thing

edit:

This is what my htaccess currently looks like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: post your .htaccess file contents too

Comment: No worries, I've edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your .htaccess file into :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ index.php
```

as initial solution to check if it works

Comment: Progress! This threw a 500 error instead of a 404. Doesn't seem to be hitting my index.php though

Comment: So you should check your httpd.conf if mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: The online line I could find in the conf file was:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

which was commented out. So I uncommented it and restart apache but it still didn't work. I saw something online about running `a2enmod rewrite` in the terminal, but it didn't work. It's worth mentioning I'm running on Windows not Unix

Comment: Your comment above is possible not complete. In your httpd.cond you should have line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so without # as first character and if you change it you need to restart Apache server

Comment: Okay I got it, I also had to set `Options` and `AllowOverride` in the `<Directory>` tags to `All`. Thanks a lot for the help!